# Count Number of Null Values in a SELECT - JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that look like such

```
sandbox=# \d child;
                               Table "public.child"
       Column        |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default
---------------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 id                  | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity
 shoe size           | text    |           |          |
 parent_id           | integer |           |          |
 status              | text    |           |          |


sandbox=# \d parent;
                    Table "public.parent"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity
 desc   | text    |           |          |
 name   | text    |           |          |
```

The data within both tables for this example is the following

child table:

```
 id | shoe size | parent id | status
----+-----------+-----------+--------
  1 | 9.5       |         1 |
  2 | 10        |         1 |
  3 | 10.5      |         1 |
  4 | 11        |         1 |
  5 | 10        |         1 |
(5 rows)
```

Parent Table

```
 id |    desc    |          name
----+------------+------------------------
  1 | some desc  | hello
```

There's 1 parent for all the children. And two of them have the same `shoe_size` of `10`.

I'm trying to do a query that can list all the distinct `child` items alongside a count of the ones where status is `null`

I want to find all the `distinct` shoe_size, name, and desc along with a count of how many of the `child`s of that combination also have a `status` of `null`.

The query I am attempting is

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    child.shoe_size
   ,parent.name
   ,parent.desc
   ,count(child.id) FILTER ( where child.status IS NULL )
FROM
   child INNER JOIN parent on child.parent_id = parent.id
GROUP BY
(
    child.size
   ,parent.name
   ,parent.desc
)
```

This is returning almost what I want except the `count` is always 1. I am hoping to get the count to be `2` where the size is `10` and `1` everywhere else

```
 size |          name          |    desc    | count
------+------------------------+------------+-------
 11   | hello                  | some desc |     1
 10.5 | hello                  | some desc |     1
 10   | hello                  | some desc |     1
 9.5  | hello                  | some desc |     1
(4 rows)
```

I think I am misunderstanding how to use the `FILTER ...where`. Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to get in one query

Comment: Just drop the `DISTINCT` - your `GROUP BY` already does this job.

Comment: Maybe one of your statuses is not null, but rather is the empty string.